# Not able to call Web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

[image]I want to bind drop down list using Web URL.[I want to call my method on load] have created function to do same but while debugging in browser its showing `Uncaught Reference Error: "`GetDataContainer`" is not Defined`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
        
        <script>        
           $(document).ready(GetDataContainer);
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  

            function GetDataContainer() {
                var params = { UserId: 'approver01', WorkflowTypeCode: 4 };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'http://IPAddress/Service.svc/getdata/MyMethodName',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: BindDataContainer,
                    error: OnErrorCall
                });
            }
```

Where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Either put them both in the same `<script>` block or call the function after you've defined it - ie move `$(document).ready(GetDataContainer);` to the end.  Alternatively, use `$(document).ready(function() { GetDataContainer(); })` so that it will be defined by the time it's called.

Comment: I tried both way but not hitting break point

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the same script block!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(GetDataContainer);

        function GetDataContainer() {
            var params = { UserId: 'approver01', WorkflowTypeCode: 4 };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://IPAddress/Service.svc/getdata/MyMethodName',
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: BindDataContainer,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });
        }
```